# Bind a class with List properties from View to Action Method in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, binding

I have a controller `HomeController` with the following action method:

```
public ActionResult DisplayData(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
   // Do something with myViewModel           
}
```

The `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    public List<CustomViewModel> CustomVM { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

And the following `View`

```
@model AppName.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView", Model);  }

<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(Model))" alt="Image" />
```

I use the `Url.Action` how it is described here but what I get in the `DisplayData` action method is null. In the source code I got:

```
<img src="/Home/DisplayData?IsSpecial=true&amp;Name=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D&amp;CustomVM=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BVestibule.AppName.ViewModels.CustomViewModel%5D"" alt="Image" />
```

so it is passing actually the type instead of the values. The only variable value passed correctly is the bool `IsSpecial`

The ViewModel instead is correctly passed to the partial view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is null exactly? Its not clear to me whats your problem. Is it the output or `Url.Action`? If so, please show the complete call.

Comment: Sorry I receive the MyViewModel with just IsSpecial with the correct values. The other two properties' value are equal to their types. From Url.Action I call the Action Method DisplayData

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" are the Lists. MVC is trying to bind the list objects themselves,not their values. See [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for an example on binding collections.

You would need to generate your URLs doing something like the following:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Names.Count(); i++)
{
 <img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", new { IsSpecial = Model.IsSpecial, Name = Model.Names[i], CustomVM = Model.CustomVM[i].Property })" alt="Image" />
}
```

**Might contain errors, I didn't test it. And it might not be the best way to do it in your case, it's just an example**

But this, of course, depends on the length of your lists. If they have different lengths, this won't work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to pass both lists to the GET action? GET is usually reserved for getting idempotent entities.

Either you might like at using a POST to send the data to the server or you would have to look at overriding the ToString() method of these lists, probably by wrapping them in your own container type.